# How to efficiently construct a B+ tree from a given list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I want to build a B+ tree from a given list of unordered elements of size `N`.

I know that the optimal bound to do it is `Θ(N / B * logM / B(N / B))` block transfers, which is also the optimal for sorting; so I can't simply pick an item and do an insert in the tree individually, since it would give me `O(N logB(N))` block transfers.

So I figured that the best way to build the tree is to sort the elements first, since the leaves are ordered anyway. From that, I'm at a loss.

I thought about something like this:

1. Take B elements from the list
2. Write them as they are somewhere (it's a leaf of the three)
3. Take the last element of the block (the biggest); it will be a routing key for the parent of the leaf
4. Repeat Step 1 for the next elements, until there are B-1 routing keys in the parent
5. When there are `B-1` routing keys in the parent, it means it's full. So the new routing key will go the "grandfather" instead (so the tree grows one level), and all the new leaves will have a new parent
6. Keep going like this until `N/B` blocks are read

Basically, the problem with this is that I'm not considering the minimum number of children that an internal node can have. So it could happen for example that a node end up with only one child, which is obviously wrong.

I looked everywhere but I couldn't find an algorithm that *actually* explains how to build a tree in `Θ(N / B * logM / B(N / B))`. All I find are algorithms with simple insertions into the tree for each item in the list, without exploiting the B factor.

Can you help me out, maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: regarding step 5, "the new routing key will go the grandfather instead", it is not the new key that goes into grandfather but the old father's middle key. the new key goes into new father

Comment: You're right, my mistake! If I split the internal nodes whenever they reach B-1 elements I can guarantee that the tree is built respecting the minimum number of children per node. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build all of the levels at the same time, which may use more than a constant number of blocks of RAM, I think that I would build the levels leafmost to rootmost (i.e., breadth-first instead of depth-first). Given the list, cut it greedily into blocks of size B. If there is only one block, then that's the root. Otherwise, if the last block has too few elements, then rebalance its elements with those of the second last block as evenly as possible; both now will have enough elements. The next list is comprised of the last element in each block of this level.

Comment: what about building relations between first and next block sets? i guess the first block set should still be in memory in order to accomplish that

Comment: With mangusta's suggestion I think that it can be done using only h + 1 blocks of size B in main memory (where h is the height of the tree); 1 block is used to load the B elements from the list (basically, the leaves) and the other h (1 block for each level) are used to store the routing keys. When one of the h block is full, it's split: the first floor((B+1)/2) elements can go in external memory since they won't be used again, the element in position ceil((B+1)/2) goes in the block in main memory related to the previous level and the remaining elements in the block stay there

Comment: @Beriol your way requires lots of I/O operations, so we're coming to tradeoff here

Comment: Why is that? I mean, there are the N/B I/O operations that are unavoidable, plus one I/O operation for each node in the tree, also unavoidable... or not?

Comment: @Beriol the way David Eisenstat suggests, one level = one write, all blocks in the same level reside in the same list, so all blocks in the same level are written at once. in your case, you have to perform write for every block

Comment: I'm kind of new to external memory algorithms and such, so help me understand. If each leaf is of size B and each internal node is B too (well, B-1), don't we need to "pay" B to write a node in the tree? I mean, we have to write each block individually no matter what (we can't write 2 blocks with 1 write operation paying only B), so why is it important to write them one after the other instead of writing one and then after a while another one next to the previous, and so on?It's not like we're writing one element at the time, we're still writing B elements at the time,that is the max isn't it?